# defer thenApplyAsync execution

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have following scenario.

```
CompletableFuture<T> result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executor);
result.thenRun(() -> {
        ...
    });
// ....
// after some more code, based on some condition I attach the thenApply() to result.

if ( x == 1) {
    result.thenApplyAsync(t -> {

        return null;
    });
}
```

The question is what if the `CompletableFuture` thread finishes the execution before the main thread reaches the `thenApplyAsync` ? does the `CompletableFuture` result shall attach itself to `thenApply`. i.e should callback be declared at the time of defining `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` itself ?

Also what is the order of execution ? `thenRun()` is always executed at last (after `thenApply()`) ?

Is there any drawback to use this strategy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing an important point. When you chain a dependent function, you are *not* altering the future you’re invoking the chaining method on.

Instead, each of these methods returns a *new* completion stage representing the dependent action.

Since you are attaching two dependent actions to `result`, which represent the `task` passed to `supplyAsync`, there is no relationship between these two actions. They may run in an arbitrary order and even at the same time in different threads.

Since you are not storing the future returned by `thenApplyAsync` anywhere, the result of its evaluation would be lost anyway. Assuming that your function returns a result of the same type as `T`, you could use

```
if(x == 1) {
    result = result.thenApplyAsync(t -> {

        return null;
    });
}
```

to replace the potentially completed future with the new future that only gets completed when the result of the specified function has been evaluated. The runnable registered at the original future via `thenRun` still does not depend on this new future. Note that `thenApplyAsync` without an executor will always use the default executor, regardless of which executor was used to complete the other future.

If you want to ensure that the `Runnable` has been successfully executed before any other stage, you can use

```
CompletableFuture<T> result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executor);
CompletableFuture<Void> thenRun = result.thenRun(() -> {
    //...
});
result = result.thenCombine(thenRun, (t,v) -> t);
```

An alternative would be

```
result = result.whenComplete((value, throwable) -> {
    //...
});
```

but here, the code will be always executed even in the exceptional case (which includes cancellation). You would have to check whether `throwable` is `null`, if you want to execute the code only in the successful case.

---

If you want to ensure that the runnable runs after both actions, the simplest strategy would be to chain it after the `if` statement, when the final completion stage is defined:

```
if(x == 1) {
    result = result.thenApplyAsync(t -> {

        return null;
    });
}
result.thenRun(() -> {
    //...
});
```

If that is not an option, you would need an incomplete future which you can complete on either result:

```
CompletableFuture<T> result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executor);

//...

CompletableFuture<T> finalStage = new CompletableFuture<>();
finalStage.thenRun(() -> {
    //...
});

// ...

if(x == 1) {
    result = result.thenApplyAsync(t -> {

        return null;
    });
}
result.whenComplete((v,t) -> {
    if(t != null) finalStage.completeExceptionally(t); else finalStage.complete(v);
});
```

The `finalStage` initially has no defined way of completion, but we can still chain dependent actions. Once we know the actual future, we can chain a handler which will complete our `finalStage` with whatever result we have.

---

As a final note, the methods without `…Async`, like `thenRun`, provide the least control over the evaluation thread. They may get executed in whatever thread completed the future, like one of `executor`’s threads in your example, but also directly in the thread calling `thenRun`, and even less intuitive, in your original example, the runnable may get executed during the unrelated `thenApplyAsync` invocation.

Comment: Thanks. is there anyway to ensure thenRun() or thenRunAysnc() to be executed after thenApplyAsync() ? I understand they can run parallelly given this scenario. I want to set certain values in thenRun only after thenAsync has run.

Comment: Thanks. isDone() returns true after the first completionstage or after all dependents are complete ?

Comment: @ulab it depends on the future on which you invoke `isDone`. If you have a dependency chain, use the last one, i.e. the one returned by `thenRun` to find out whether the entire operation has been completed. Otherwise, always keep in mind that you have a bunch of individual `CompletableFuture` instances, each of them having its own completion state.

Comment: exactly what i wanted!